# Issue with Http Client in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android app development, and one of my clients asked me to fix this code his past dev left the job . there were a lot of errors I was able to fix it. But now I am stuck at a point in HTTP request error in java and cannot execute this code. Let me know how to fix it. Current status complied SDK 33 and cannot downgrade the same. Code below. HTTP client is deprecated.

```
package com.ecom.ecommerce;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ActivityCategoryList extends Activity {

GridView listCategory;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;

// declare adapter object to create custom category list
AdapterCategoryList cla;

// create arraylist variables to store data from server
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();

String CategoryAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_list);
    
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new             
   ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    bar.setTitle("Category");
    
    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listCategory = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    
    cla = new AdapterCategoryList(ActivityCategoryList.this);

    // category API url
    CategoryAPI = Constant.CategoryAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;
    
    // call asynctask class to request data from server
    new getDataTask().execute();
    
    // event listener to handle list when clicked
    listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // go to menu page
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList.this, ActivityMenuList.class);
            iMenuList.putExtra("category_id", Category_ID.get(position));
            iMenuList.putExtra("category_name", Category_name.get(position));
            startActivity(iMenuList);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        }
    });
    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.cart:
        // refresh action
        Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList.this, ActivityCart.class);
        startActivity(iMyOrder);
        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        return true;
        
    case R.id.refresh:
        IOConnect = 0;
        listCategory.invalidateViews();
        clearData();
        new getDataTask().execute();
        return true;
        
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        return true;
        
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData(){
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    
    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        
        // if internet connection and data available show data on list
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Category_ID.size() > 0) && (IOConnect == 0)){
            listCategory.setVisibility(0);
            listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONData(){
    
    clearData();
    
    try {
        // request data from Category API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));
    
        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }
    
        // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 
            
            JSONObject category = object.getJSONObject("Category");
            
            Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(category.getString("Category_ID")));
            Category_name.add(category.getString("Category_name"));
            Category_image.add(category.getString("Category_image"));
            Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));
                
        }
            
            
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //cla.imageLoader.clearCache();
    listCategory.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}

}
```

Comment: Tell your client that you need to upgrade whole network implementation. You need to be paid more to upgrade.

Comment: Haha, What are the solutions?

Comment: This is very old stuff, which is not supported in new sdks , you can't downgrade so your only option is replace this with [HTTPURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) or retrofit or volley networking libraries.

Comment: Thanks. If possible can you fix this code or certain section with HTTP URL connection method so that I can get an idea, on how to implement the method.